# What does #encoding BINARY mean in the Ruby code?

Tags: ruby

There is a line `#encoding BINARY` in the beginning of the code, what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

http://ruby.runpaint.org/encoding

> Ruby defines an encoding named ASCII-8BIT, with an alias of BINARY, which does not correspond to any known encoding. It is intended to be associated with binary data, such as the bytes that make up a PNG image, so has no restrictions on content. One byte always corresponds with one character. This allows a String, for instance, to be treated as bag of bytes rather than a sequence of characters. ASCII-8BIT, then, effectively corresponds to the absence of an encoding, so methods that expect an encoding name recognise nil as a synonym.

Answer (score 0):

That line is how we tell the Ruby interpreter to expect a certain character set in the source file.

James Grey has a great series on dealing with [character encodings](http://blog.grayproductions.net/categories/character_encodings) in Ruby. In particular, "[Ruby 1.9's Three Default Encodings](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings) " might be good reading if you want to understand the details.